# Show that if $T$ is a subset of $S$ having more than $16$ elements then $T$ contains two elements whose distance is at most $2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $S = \{0000000, 0000001, ... , 1111111 \}$ be the set of all
>   binary sequences of length $7$. The **distance** of two elements $s_1
> ,s_2 \in S$ is the number of places in which $s_1$ and $s_2$ differ.
>   Show that if $T$ is a subset of $S$ having more than $16$ elements
>   then $T$ contains two elements whose distance is at most $2$.

For example, $0001011$ and $1001010$ have distance $2$, since they differ in positions $1$ and $7$.

This problem is not clear to me. I think it's possible to take the pigeonhole principe.

Does someone could help me solve the problem? OR even just a hint would be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each word has exactly $7$ words at distance $1$, so it "occupies" a total of $8$ words. $17\cdot 8>128$.

Comment: This is implicitly using that if two words occupy a "common" word then those words have distance $2$ or less.

Comment: Is it possible to slightly develop your hint. I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Say $B(s)$ is the set of all words at distance no more than $1$ from $s$. Then each $B(s)$ has $8$ elements. Now given $17$ words $s_1,\dots,s_{17}$, the sets $B(s_j)$ cannot all be disjoint, since $17\cdot 8>128$. But if $B(s_j)$ and $B(s_k)$ intersect then the distance from $s_j$ to $s_k$ is no more than $2$.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an element $s$ with the function $B$? I can not find the 8 elements that you mentioned.

Comment: If my element is $0100100$, that should I have as an element in $B(0100100)$?

Comment: when we have $0100100$ we get $B(0100100)=\{0100100, 1100100,0000100,0110100,0101100,010000,0100110,0100101\}$

Comment: Why $B(s_j)$ cannot all be disjoint, since $17\cdot 8>128$?

Comment: Why if $B(s_j)$ and $B(s_k)$ intersect then the distance from $s_j$ to $s_k$ is no more than $2$?

Comment: Well, assume a word $w$ has distance $1$ from $a$ and $b$. Then we can get from $a$ to $w$ by changing one letter, and from $w$ to $b$ by changing at most one letter. Therefore if we do these movements in a row we can get from $a$ to $b$ by changing at most two letters, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The argument given by Hagen can be generalized a bit. If you have a set $S$ of $k$ binary words of length $n$ that are at distance at least $d$ apart then for each word $w$ you can consider the set of words that are at distance $n/2$ or less from $w$. These sets are going to contain $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\dots \binom{n}{d/2}$ words each and are going to be disjoint, since if $w$ and $w'$ had a common word in their sets then $w$ and $w'$ would be at distance less than $d$ apart, which does not happen because of the construction of $S$). This is going to prove the existance of at least $k(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\dots \binom{n}{d/2})$ words, which is a contradiction whenever that product is larger than $2^n$.

In our case $n=7,k=17,d=2$ and indeed we obtain:

$17(\binom{7}{0}+\binom{7}{1})>2^7$.

I learned this technique trying to solve the following slightly harder problem from a brazilian olympiad:

Show that we cannot form more than $4096$ binary sequences of length $24$ so that any two differ in at least $8$ positions.